# button action listener for text field doesnt work

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

I tried to make this GUI program which take input from the user by text field and should return it with uppercase convertion:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class gui {
 JTextField textField;
 JFrame frame;
 JButton button;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    gui tr = new gui();
    tr.go();
}

public void go() {  
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField("Type here);
    JButton button = new JButton("Send");
    button.addActionListener(new buttonListener());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textField);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

class buttonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String txt;
        txt = textField.getText();
        txt = txt.toUpperCase();
        textField.setText(txt);
    }
}
}
```

The file respond by null pointer exception. Ive tried to add exception handler, and to change the program based on instances Ive seen online. please explain to me my mistake.
Thank you.

Comment: Where is the null pointer exception?

Comment: You're shadowing variables. In the future, search on the problem and you'd find the solution easily yourself. A search on NullPointerExceptions will show you the duplicate that explains how to find the null variable, and once you've done that you would have quickly found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your class member `JTextField textField` is never initialized, yet you are trying to use it within your `actionPerformed`

Inside your `go()` method you create a new `JTextField textField` that has nothing do to with the original `textField`.

In fact inside `go()` you basically create new objects

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JTextField textField = new JTextField("Type here);
JButton button = new JButton("Send");
```

Instead of initializing those already defined for your class.

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating another local variable inside your `go()` method. Change this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(“Type here”);
```

To:

```
textField = new JTextField(“Type here”);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!